# Using try/catch with C++ arrays

Tags: c++, try-catch

I'm trying to make a Blackjack simulator. Player is a class that stores cards dealt from the deck. How to use try/catch to write this function?

```
void Player::acceptCard(Card c)
{
    //        as long as there is space in the array myCards, place Card c into myCards
    //        if there is not enough space for another card, throw an exception
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer a simple boolean return here over exceptions:

In C++ you can't be sure whether your exception will be caught somewhere (opposed to e.g. Java). If someone uses your classes interface he doesn't know about exceptions which can be thrown (unless he has a look at the documentation, of course). But a return type is immediately visible. In the company I'm currently working we're using exceptions not for *errors* (e.g. not enough space in an array) but for *exceptions* (something happened which leaves you no choice but to maybe write some error log and then exit your application)

But: If you want to do it nevertheless:

1. Create your own exception type which inherits from `std::exception`
2. Throw that exception
3. Surround your function call with try ... catch